# Подсчет процента выпадения орлов при подбрасывании монеты

Tags: python

есть задача написать функцию которая проводит не менее 100 случаев подбрасывания монеты 10 раз. Функция должна возвращать словарь, где ключи — это количество возможных выпадений орлов (от 0 до 10), а значения — это проценты от того, сколько это количество орлов выпало во всех случаях.
Подбрасывание монет необходимое количество раз, я написал, но во первых у меня формируется много словарей, а нужен один, во вторых не могу сообразить как посчитать процент?

```
from random import randint


def coin():
    for i in range(100):
        new_dict = {i: 1 if randint(0, 1) == 1 else 0 for i in range(10)}

coin()
```

Comment: процент это  количество выпадений орла поделить на общее количество бросков и умножить на 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делайте по шагам:

```
from random import randint

dct = {i:0 for i in range(11)}

for _ in range(100):
    eagles = sum([randint(0,1) for _ in range(10)])
    dct[eagles] += 1

print(dct)

>>>{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 12, 4: 16, 5: 24, 6: 21, 7: 10, 8: 7, 9: 4, 10: 1}
```

Для ровно ста прогонов получаются уже проценты, иначе (для n прогонов) нужно результаты умножать на 100/n

Comment: Спасибо, а n в моем случае это 10?

Comment: Нет, n = 100.  Но по условиям оно может быть и больше, например - 150 или 200

Comment: хорошо, подскажите пожалуйста, а если нужно 10 000 раз подбрасывать, то тогда как процент посчитать?

Comment: Эээ... Вы осознаёте, что у вас проводится сто (или более) сеансов, в каждом из которых делается десять бросков?  10000 к чему относится?

Comment: 10000 случаев подбрасывания

Comment: Я уже написал в ответе, что нужно делать. В конце значения в словаре умножить на 100/10000

Comment: @Константин Ну что, разобралиcь?

Comment: Да, конечно, спасибо за помощь